# Difficulty passing variables from a two page sign up

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two pages of form for the sign up process. Both forms feed into two different tables. users and user_profile. I am looking into using $_SESSIONS to pass a unique attribute from the first page to the second so that that there will be a relationship for each user on both tables. The ID column is incremental so i decided to use the username column because it is unique. Now i am having difficulty passing the username from the first page unto the second page so that i can add it to the insert statement for the sql. My code on the first page is as follows

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = '';
$_SESSION['var_user'] = 'username';
....
```

username is the name of the field from the formand on the second page, i have

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = '';
$username = $_SESSION['var_user'];
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "webdev");
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$houseno = ($_POST['str_number']);
$street =($_POST['str_name']);
$city = ($_POST['city']);
$county = ($_POST['county']);
$postcode = ($_POST['pst_code']);
$skills = ($_POST['skills']);
$_username = ($_POST[$username]);
$sql = ("INSERT INTO users_profile (house_no, street_name, city, county, 
postcode, about_me, username) VALUES ('$houseno', '$street', '$city', 
'$county', '$postcode', '$skills', '$_username')");        
     if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration succesful! Added $username to the database!";
                    header("location: index.html");
}       else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration Unsuccessful, Please login and update your information';
}
}
```

I have tried everything from using hidden input in the form. Doesn't seem to be working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of storing the name of the field to the session, you need to store it's value.

Comment: the username will be supplied on the first page. also i tried `$_SESSION['var_user'] = '$username';` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Use double quotes around $username or leave the quotes off in order to get it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$username` as an key on the second page:

```
$username = $_SESSION['var_user'];
...
$_username = ($_POST[$username]);
```

Instead you should simply define it on the first page:

```
$_SESSION['var_user'] = $_POST['var_user']
```

And use it on the second page:

```
$username = $_SESSION['var_user'];
```

Comment: Do you mean `$_SESSION['var_user'] = $_POST[$username]` in the first page. Like i said, `username` is the name of the field in the form and not `var user`

Comment: Then you should make it `$_SESSION['var_user'] = $_POST['username']`